# How to debug SSL/TLS in server side

Tags: web-services, iis, ssl, encryption

I have an application which connects to the server using ssl/tls protocol, what I want to know is in which cipher does it choses to do the handshake, my application server is on IIS win2008r2 , thou I can tell it to connect to which ever address.

I know such solution exists to check what types of ciphers the server is allowing (like sslscan, or the ssllabs website) but I need it the other way around.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The handshake isn't done 'in' a cipher suite. The handshake is used to *decide* the cipher suite, which only becomes effective afterwards. And why do you think you need to know what it is at the server?

Comment: Already figured the problem I was having, maybe I didn't explained my self properly, In the handshake the cipher is decided, my client offered the server a suite it couldn't work with, I needed to see what is that suite so I can debug the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to look at request stream in order to see which cipher the client and server negotiated. I don't think that the handshake is encrypted at this point so you shouldn't even need to configure wireshark with the private key of the web server to decrypt the request stream.

Comment: I also found a little program called ssltap, it is a tiny proxy the can generate a nice HTML report for the ssl session